# ¿Porqué o qué sucede en la siguiente comparación de integer con string? PHP

Tags: php, operador, booleano

### Practicando php

Resulta que he estado aprendiendo PHP, yo ya manejo otros lenguajes, pero me encontré con esta duda al estudiar php.

### Operadores de comparación que evalúan el tipo de datos

Comprendo que hay operadores que evalúan el tipo de dato en php como !== o ===, pero al usar la siguiente comparación me salio la siguiente duda:

```
<?php
$a = "a";
$b = 10;

if($b>$a)
echo "true" ;
else echo "false";
?>
```

El resultado es `true` ¿Porqué?

Comment: del manual php [Si el string empieza con un dato numérico válido, éste será el valor empleado. De lo contrario, el valor será 0.](http://il.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Answer (score 1):

PHP al ser un lenguaje con tipeado debil (*Weak Typed*) al ver una comparación de un número (entero/decimal) intenta convertir el valor de la cadena a un número.

En tu ejemplo tienes

```
$a = "a";
$b = 10;
```

`$a` al comenzar con un valor no numérico, simplemente toma el valor como inválido, y en lugar de convertirlo a `NaN` lo convierte a `0`

Si en tu ejemplo `$a` tuviera un valor que comience con un número, este se convertiría hasta el punto que el siguiente caracter se convierta en un `NaN`. Por ejemplo:

```
$b = 10;
$a = "12345";
if($b>$a) //En este caso $a vale 12345, por lo tanto es FALSE

$a = "1abc";
if($b>$a) //En este caso $a vale 1, por lo tanto es TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Cualquier string **formado por letras** al hacer una comparación es igual a `0`.

En tu caso `10 > 0`

En cambio si el string fuese númerico si que se podría hacer una conversión a int para que te haga la comparación.

Ejemplo:

```
$a = "a";
$a = (int) $a; // Devuelve 0

$a = "123";
$a = (int) $a; // Devuelve 123
```

Para más información sobre las conversiones de tipo automáticas que hace PHP tienes esta página: [Conversiones de Tipos](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.type-juggling.php)